# meaning of the word "mask" in computer science

Tags: computer-science, mask

what is the meaning of the word "mask" in computer science?

I find this word in Webster Dictionary, But all explains are talking about "Face Lid". Fake face?

Comment: [Look beyond dictionaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mask is bitmask in full it is just a data that is used for bitwise operations usually in bitfields (data structure).